# Can I use Laravel 5 to clone a select box and still use form model binding?

Tags: php, laravel-5, jquery-select2, model-binding, jquery-cloneya

(Please excuse the multifaceted question!)

Basically the question is; how can I use Laravel 5 functionality to clone a select box, save that data, and( as a bonus) when returning to the form have the data displayed using form model binding. So if there is one work experience "group" (being company and position) or many they would all be displayed correctly.

I created a form with fields as below:

```
<div class="workexperience">
<!--Work Experience / position   -->
<!--  Form Input -->
<div class="form-group">
{!!Form::label('positions_list', 'Work Experience:')!!}
{!!Form::select('positions_list', $positions, null, ['id'=> 'positions_list', 'class'=>'form-control','multiple'])!!}
</div>
<!--company-->
<div class="form-group" >
{!!Form::label('companies_list', 'Company:')!!}
{!!Form::select('companies_list', $companies, null, ['id'=>'companies_list','class'=>'form-control','multiple'])!!}
</div>
</div>
<div id="workexperience-placeholder"></div>
<a onclick="cloneMe('#workexperience')" class="btn btn-default btn-block"><span class="icon-entypo icon-plus"></span><b>Add Another</b></a>
```

and am using jquery clone to allow the user to add in new sets of positions and companies

```
function cloneMe(thisDiv)
{
$(thisDiv).clone(false).insertBefore(thisDiv+"-placeholder:last")

}
```

Visually this seems to work as it does clone the boxes. However I am using Select2 to create a "tag" effect ( from Laracasts-23  'Syncing Tags'!) and if there is already data selected in the dropdown ( effectively a "Tag") when I click to clone the boxes that data is carried across into the new cloned field.

How do I clone in such a way that the selected item is not carried across? I have tried to use jquery such as:

```
.find("input").val('').end()
```

but am having no luck (I have tried select instead of input in the above as well)

I am sure that what I am trying to do is actually fairly common but just struggling to find a way to do it. (I also tried cloneya but that seemed to conflict with Select2.)

If you have suggestions on how I can improve my question please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Mhluzi

Comment: What version of Select2?

Comment: Hi  @kevin-brown - the version of Select2 is " Select2 4.0.0-rc.2"

Comment: Ok, getting there slowly...
if I clone just one select box I can use:
    .removeAttr("selected")
    .val([])

But I am still having no luck if I try to clone the whole div. I don't know how to target the individual newly cloned selects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by targeting each individual select :

```
$('.positions').select2("destroy");
$('#workexperience').clone(true).insertBefore("#workexperience-placeholder:last")
.end();
$('.positions:last').removeAttr("selected")
.val([])
.end();
$('.positions').select2(
{
placeholder: 'Current or last position',
maximumSelectionLength: 1,
tags: true
});
```

Not very elegant but it works for me.